# Filterable Image Gallery Matching Problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is exactly when I click on the buttons above, I want the places I assign "data-category" to come, but there may be a problem with the codes I wrote in javascript. I tried a question class problem. I don't want you to get stuck on the hover feature, that's not the problem. I just want the items to come up when I click. thanks.

```js
const imageGallery = document.querySelector("#img-filter");
const filterOptions = imageGallery.querySelectorAll(".filter-options button");
const parentinner = document.querySelectorAll("[data-category]");

const showImages = (category) => {
  parentinner.forEach((image) => {
    if (
      image.getAttribute("data-category") === category ||
      category === "all"
    ) {
      image.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      image.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
};

filterOptions.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const category = button.getAttribute("data-filter");
    showImages(category);
  });
});
```

```css
section .projects .filter-options button {
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #c4c2c2;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #fff;
}

section .projects .filter-options button:hover {
  background: #0d6efd;
  color: #fff;
}

section .parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

section .div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  display: none;
}

section .div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  display: none;
}

section .div3 {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
  display: none;
}

section .div4 {
  grid-area: 1 / 4 / 3 / 5;
  display: none;
}

section .div5 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  display: none;
}

section .div6 {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
  display: none;
}

section .parent .div1,
section .parent .div2,
section .parent .div3,
section .parent .div4,
section .parent .div5,
section .parent .div6 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

section .parent .info-hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(161, 0, 161, 0.75);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

section .parent .info-hover h6 {
  padding: 5px 12px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 13px;
  width: 86.5px;
}

section .parent .info-hover .a-down {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

section .parent .info-hover .a-sub a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

section .parent .div1:hover .info-hover,
section .parent .div2:hover .info-hover,
section .parent .div3:hover .info-hover,
section .parent .div4:hover .info-hover,
section .parent .div5:hover .info-hover,
section .parent .div6:hover .info-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  section .parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
  }
  section .div1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  }
  section .div2 {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  }
  section .div3 {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  }
  section .div4 {
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / 5 / 2;
  }
  section .div5 {
    grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
  }
  section .div6 {
    grid-area: 4 / 2 / 5 / 3;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  section .parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
  }
  section .div1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
  }
  section .div2 {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 3;
  }
  section .div3 {
    grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 3;
  }
  section .div4 {
    grid-area: 5 / 1 / 7 / 3;
  }
  section .div5 {
    grid-area: 7 / 1 / 8 / 3;
  }
  section .div6 {
    grid-area: 8 / 1 / 9 / 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://cdn.lineicons.com/3.0/lineicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
  <div class="container project">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="container projects flex-wrap text-center pt-3 pb-5" id="img-filter">
        <div class="filter-options">

          <button type="button" class="bg-primary text-white rounded-5 px-3 py-2 me-2" data-filter="all">Show All</button>

          <button type="button" class="rounded-5 px-3 py-2 me-2" data-filter="marketing">Marketing</button>

          <button type="button" class="rounded-5 px-3 py-2 me-2" data-filter="business">Business</button>

          <button type="button" class="rounded-5 px-3 py-2 me-2 mt-3 mt-sm-0" data-filter="finance">Finance</button>

          <button type="button" class="rounded-5 px-3 py-2 mt-3 mt-md-0" data-filter="consulting">Consulting</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="parent pb-5">
        <div class="div1 parentinner">
          <div class="info-hover p-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" data-category="marketing">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <h6 class="text-dark mb-3">Marketing</h6>
              <a href="#" class="a-sub text-white text-decoration-none fw-semibold">Stock Market Analysis</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="a-down rounded align-content-center p-2 rounded-circle">
              <i class="lni lni-arrow-right text-primary fw-semibold"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/870/200" alt=".." class="img-fluid ">
        </div>
        <div class="div2 parent-inner">
          <div class="info-hover p-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" data-category="business">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <h6 class="text-dark mb-3">Business</h6>
              <a href="#" class="a-sub text-white text-decoration-none fw-semibold">Sales Analysis</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="a-down rounded align-content-center p-2 rounded-circle">
              <i class="lni lni-arrow-right text-primary fw-semibold"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/872/200" alt=".." class="img-fluid ">
        </div>
        <div class="div3 parent-inner">
          <div class="info-hover p-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" data-category="marketing">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <h6 class="text-dark mb-3">Marketing</h6>
              <a href="#" class="a-sub text-white text-decoration-none fw-semibold">Stock Investments</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="a-down rounded align-content-center p-2 rounded-circle">
              <i class="lni lni-arrow-right text-primary fw-semibold"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/873/200" alt=".." class="img-fluid ">
        </div>
        <div class="div4 parent-inner">
          <div class="info-hover p-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" data-category="business">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <h6 class="text-dark mb-3">Business</h6>
              <a href="#" class="a-sub text-white text-decoration-none fw-semibold">Big Data Services</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="a-down rounded align-content-center p-2 rounded-circle">
              <i class="lni lni-arrow-right text-primary fw-semibold"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/874/200" alt=".." class="img-fluid ">
        </div>
        <div class="div5 parent-inner">
          <div class="info-hover p-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" data-category="finance">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <h6 class="text-dark mb-3">Finance</h6>
              <a href="#" class="a-sub text-white text-decoration-none fw-semibold">Sales Enablement</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="a-down rounded align-content-center p-2 rounded-circle">
              <i class="lni lni-arrow-right text-primary fw-semibold"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/875/200" alt=".." class="img-fluid ">
        </div>
        <div class="div6 parent-inner">
          <div class="info-hover p-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" data-category="consulting">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <h6 class="text-dark mb-3">Consulting</h6>

              <a href="#" class="a-sub text-white text-decoration-none fw-semibold">Consulting Services</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="a-down rounded align-content-center p-2 rounded-circle">
              <i class="lni lni-arrow-right text-primary fw-semibold"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/877/200" alt=".." class="img-fluid ">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [Filterable Image Gallery using HTML, CSS & Javascript - DEV Community ‍‍](https://dev.to/shantanu_jana/filterable-image-gallery-using-html-css-javascript-49ij)

Comment: I did similar to this. problem solved. close topic.